# Is F# case sensitive?

Tags: f#, case-insensitive, case-sensitive

I searched here and on the net but no answer.

The reason I ask is, since F# conventions seems like they favor noncapital letters, using BCL types with Pascal conventions look weird in F#, as in:

```
let stringD = String.Join(" ",[| stringA; stringB |])
```

Seems like it would be more in the spirit of F# like this:

```
let stringD = string.join(" ",[| stringA; stringB |])
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, a few things.

First, F# is case-sensitive.

Second, the F# conventions for naming are described in the [F# Component Design Guidelines](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/fsharp-component-design-guidelines.pdf)
.  Briefly, let-bound members inside F# modules use camelCase, but all .NET OO constructs use PascalCase.  This is true throughout the F# library.

Finally, in F# `string` is not a keyword, rather it is both the name of a [type abbreviation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370299.aspx) (for `System.String`) and the name of a [function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340491.aspx) (that converts to a string).  In the expression context of `string.Join`, the function name takes precedence, which is why `string.Join` does not work.  And because of case-sensitivity, `System.String.join` would never work (unless e.g. you added an extension member).

Comment: Thanks amazing answer. Looks like I will be asking you a lot of F# questions here if you don't mind :O

Answer (score 2):

Yes, F# is case-sensitive

```
let stringD = string.join(" ",[| stringA; stringB |])
```

Will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, [the F# Language Specification](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html) does not explicitly mention case-sensitivity, but does refer to using different casing for intrinsics/language and user-defined type parameters (5.1.2)

Whilst my experience with F# is limited (beyond Hello World-style apps) I would assume that `string.join` does not bind to `String.Join`.

Comment: Ok I can understand Join being not found in String, but in C# string or String works to access it's members. Why doesn't this work in F#? Is this some IDE magic behind the covers for C#?

Comment: In C#, 'string' is a keyword that means 'System.String'.  In F#, 'string' is the name of a function as well as a type alias, and not a keyword.